# navbar bootstrap não está no topo da página

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

eu estou no começo da produção de um site, porém meu navbar não fica no top, ele fica no meio da pág:

[image: print]

o meu html está assim:

```
<body>  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(página atual)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ação</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Outra ação</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Algo mais aqui</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Desativado</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

o meu css não tem basicamente nada ainda, apenas para a imagem de fundo:

```
body{
    background-image: url("../img/backpage.jpg");
    background-color: rgba(64, 118, 182, 1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
```

se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Como você está usando Bootstrap eu suponho, basta acrescentar a classe *fixed-top* na sua navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

Espero que tenha ajudado. :)